# Comma separated email validation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript

I am using the following link for validating email:
http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/04/validate-email-address-using-jquery.html

I am using this function to validate my email address using js:

```
validateEmail = (sEmail) ->
  filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/
  if filter.test(sEmail)
    true
  else
    false
$(document).ready (e) ->
  $("#invitation_form").submit ->
    sEmail = $("#invitation_email").val().split(',')
    email=0
    for email in [0..sEmail.length]
      if $.trim(email).length is 0
        $("h2").append("<div class='alert alert-error'>Please review the problems below</div>")
        $("#invitation_email").attr("placeholder", "Email can't be blank")
        return false
      if validateEmail(email)
      else
        alert sEmail
        email++
        # $("h2").append("<div class='alert alert-error'>Please review the problems below</div>");
        # $("#invitation_email").val('')
        # $("#invitation_email").attr("placeholder", "Please enter valid email")
        # return false
```

This is validating my email properly if I put only one email. But in my email text field I have to put many comma separated emails and then validate each email individually. For that I had put split(','), and the added the for loop but the validation is not done properly. If I put 'example1@email.com, example2@email.com', then its going in the else block which is for invalid emails. In the alert I am getting the individual emails but not getting how to validate each email individually.
Can someone please help me in this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say this:

```
for email in [0..sEmail.length]
```

you're saying:

```
for email in an_array_of_numbers
```

so the `email` values inside that loop will be integers and integers aren't email addresses. You say that:

> This is validating my email properly if I put only one email.

but that's not true, it fails with one email address or many as you can see in this demo:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7LFus/

If you want to look at the email addresses in `sEmail`, then you want:

```
for i in [0...sEmail.length]
  email = sEmail[i]
  #...
```

or better:

```
for email in sEmail
  #...
```

Note that the first version uses `...` instead of your `..`, `..` includes the upper limit so if `sEmail.length` is one you'd be iterating over `[0, 1]` rather than the `[0]` that would match the array's indexes. I'd go with the `for email in sEmail` version rather than worrying about indexes.

Also, [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) can take a regex as the splitting pattern so you could removing the leading and trailing whitespace while splitting:

```
sEmail = $("#invitation_email").val().split(/\s*,\s*/)
```

That way you don't have to `$.trim` inside the loop and you won't forget to trim when calling `validateEmail`.

While I'm here, [`Regexp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Regexp/test) returns `true` or `false` so you don't need to say:

```
if filter.test(sEmail)
  true
else
  false
```

you can simply say:

```
filter.test(sEmail)
```

So just a couple small changes and you should have something that is cleaner and works better.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SzzXV/

Comment: Tried for the above fiddle also but still return false is not working. Don't understand where I am missing. Had written the following:

Comment: $("invitation_form").submit ->
  sEmail = $("#invitation_email").val().split(/\s*,\s*/)
  for email in sEmail
    if email.length is 0
      return false
      $("h2").append("<div class='alert alert-error'>Please review problems</div>")
      $("#invitation_email").attr("placeholder", "Email can't be blank")
    else if(!validateEmail(email))
      $("h2").append("<div class='alert alert-error'>Please review problems</div>");
      $("#invitation_email").val('')
      $("#invitation_email").attr("placeholder", "Enter valid email")
      return false
    else
      return true

Comment: I don't want the form to be submitted if the email is invalid or blank  thats why had written return false on the submit of form

Comment: If you don't want the form to submit then add appropriate `return`s, the code above is just a demonstration of the technique, hence the use of a click handler and no `return`s. And pasting CoffeeScript into a comment doesn't work very well.

Comment: Yes I had added the returns. The mistake I did was that I hadn't added hash(#) with the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a while statement instead. Like this:

```
sEmailArray = $("#invitation_email").val().split(',')
i = 0
email = undefined
while email = sEmailArray[i]
  if validateEmail(email)
  else
    alert email
  i++
```

Comment: @benjaminjosephw- Thanks, the suggestion that you gave is working perfect for multiple emails but if I put invalid or blankl email then 'return false' is not working. Following is the code:

Comment: $("#invitation_form").submit ->
  sEmail = $("#invitation_email").val().split(',')
  i = 0
  email = undefined
  while email = sEmail[i]
    if $.trim(email).length is 0
      $("h2").append("<div class='alert alert-error'>Please review problem</div>")
      $("#invitation_email").attr("placeholder","Email can't be blank")
      return false
    if validateEmail(email)
    else
      $("h2").append("<div class='alert alert-error'>Please review problems</div>");
      $("#invitation_email").val('')
      $("#invitation_email").attr("placeholder","Enter valid email")
      return false
    i++